# How do I enable the wireless network adapter on centos 7 minimal install?

Tags: centos, wifi, networkmanager

I have just installed CentOS 7 over an old windows PC. The CentOS 7 image was of minimal install as I had only 4 GB of pendrive available.

The wifi driver named **wlp18s0b1** shows in the list if I do `ip link` but it's configuration file is not there in the */etc/sysconfig/network-scritps/* so I can't enable this interface using `ifup`. `ifup wlp18s0b1` says the following.

/sbin/ifup: configuration for wlp18s0b1 not found.
Usage: ifup

The option `nmcli d` shows the wifi device **wlp18s0b1** listed along with the ethernet card but when I do `nmcli conn up` it says the following .

```
Error: unknown connection wlp18s0b1
```

I am not sure how to bring this device up with `nmcli` and I don't have any extra network tools such as `iw, iwconfig, ifconfig, dhclient` available as it was a minimal install.

I only have access to wifi from here so can't use ethernet to install these as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly connect to a wireless network using `nmcli`:

```
nmcli d wifi c <SSID> --ask
```

This will connect to the specified SSID, ask you for the passphrase, and configure the entire connection for you.

You are meant to use the literal word `wifi`, not the interface name. NetworkManager will find your WiFi interface on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Install wireless tools by running the following command as root:

```
 yum install wireless-tools
```

Create the configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlps0f0` if it doesn't exist:

```
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
IPV6INIT=no
DNS2=8.8.4.4
BROADCAST=192.168.0.255
USERCTL=no
DNS1=8.8.8.8
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=""
MACADDR=""
TYPE=Ethernet
DEVICE=wan0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
MTU=""
IPADDR=192.168.0.101
NETWORK=192.168.0.0
ONBOOT=no
```

finally start dhcp client:

```
dhclient
```

or

```
systemctl restart Network-manager
```

Comment: in CentOS 8 you can install wifi tools using `dnf install NetworkManager-wifi*`